# How to display output data from function in Django template?

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates, django-views, python-requests

The index function retrieves a string from 'n url and prints the desired output to the terminal. How do I set up my views so that it displays the data on my index html page?

This is for a weather app that needs to retrieve data from a URL and display it on a page where a user has logged in. I have tried using context but I'm not sure how to use it with data that is returned from the for loop.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json


def index(request):
    url = "http://weather.news24.com/ajaxpro/Weather.Code.Ajax,Weather.ashx"

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
           'Host': 'weather.news24.com',
           'Origin': 'http://weather.news24.com',
           'Referer': 'http://weather.news24.com/sa/capetown',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) '
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
           'X-AjaxPro-Method': 'GetForecast7Day'}

    payload = {"cityId": "77107"}

    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    weather_data = r.json()

    for forecast in weather_data['value']['Forecasts']:
        print(forecast['ShortWeekDay'] + ':', 'High: ' + forecast['HighTemp'] + 'C',
          'Low: ' + forecast['LowTemp'] + 'C',
          'Wind Speed: ' + forecast['WindSpeed'] + 'Km/h', 'Rainfall: ' + str(forecast['Rainfall']))

    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', )
```

The expected results would be displaying the data from the database or from the output of the function. Currently it's only printing the data from the URL. I'm not sure where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the whole list with forecast objects and iterate it in your `weather/index.html`.

```
def index(request):
    ....
    context = {
        'forecasts': weather_data['value']['Forecasts']
    }
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context)
```

Since a single `forecast` in your `weather_data['value']['Forecasts']` is a dictionary as well you need to create a **[template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)** allowing you to access dictionary values by key inside a dictionary through django templates. I don't know why they haven't implemented it so far since it's a common issue but here is what you need:

```
@register.filter
def get_value(dict, key):
    return dict[key]
```

Then inside `weather/index.html` you can access it like (I don't know it's structure so I'll write a pseudo):

```
{% for forecast in forecasts %}
    <h1>ShortWeekDay: {{forecast|get_value:"ShortWeekDay"}}</h1>
    <h2>High: {{forecast|get_value:"HighTemp"}}C</h2>
    <h2>Low: {{forecast|get_value:"LowTemp"}}C</h2>
    <h2>Wind Speed: {{forecast|get_value:"WindSpeed"}}Km/h</h2>
    <h2>Rainfall: {{forecast|get_value:"Rainfall"}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```